# Why can a DOM element have up to two identical namespace declarations?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, xml-namespaces

**TL;DR: Why can I end up with a DOM that serializes to this?**

```xml
<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:test="http://example.com/test" 
  xmlns:test="http://example.com/test">
...
</svg>
```

I need to modify an SVG graphic that is inlined into a HTML page, which involves adding elements and attributes using a namespace, `http://example.com/test` which shall be bound to the prefix `test`.

The original SVG document may have no such namespace:

```xml
<svg id="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>
```

Or it might already by declared like this:

```xml
<svg id="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:test="http://example.com/test">...</svg>
```

So I think I need to add the namespace to the `svg` root element like that:

```js
svgRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:test", "http://example.com/test");
```

I was careless and executed this line on each document, no matter if the namespace was already declared or not, because I thought I would just overwrite it with the same content. But now I have lots of documents which have 0, 1 or 2 of the the same namespace declarations.

What's even more confusing, if my source document has 2 or more of those identical namespace declarations, and I add 1, 2 or even more afterwards, in the end the total sum of identical namespace declarations is always 2, never more than that.

This behavior is identical across Firefox 92, Chrome 93 and Safari 14, so it seems like it's intended. Anyway, the Web Developer DOM Inspector in Firefox somehow gets stuck and stops updating the DOM when the second namespace declaration is added.

Here's a minimal example for the *2 + 2 = 2* case. Note that I removed the code where I actually *use* the namespace binding for brevity:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Namespace Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is an SVG graphic:<br />
    <svg id="img" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:test="http://example.com/test"
        xmlns:test="http://example.com/test">
        <ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" />
    </svg>
    <script>
        var svgRoot = document.getElementById("img");
        svgRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:test", "http://example.com/test");
        svgRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:test", "http://example.com/test");
        alert("Result: " + svgRoot.outerHTML);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `xmlns:test` is not valid from the SVG NameSpace, so the one in the markup will be declared in the `null` namespace.

```js
var svgRoot = document.querySelector("svg");
console.log(svgRoot.attributes[1].namespaceURI);
```

```html
This is an SVG graphic:<br />
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:test="http://example.com/test">
</svg>
```

Then, the one in the JS will correctly be set to the XMLNS NameSpace:

```js
var svgRoot = document.querySelector("svg");
// here the name space is different than in the markup
svgRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:test", "http://example.com/test");
console.log(svgRoot.attributes[0].namespaceURI);
```

```html
This is an SVG graphic:<br />
<svg>
</svg>
```

Both attribute being set from a different NameSpace, they can cohabit on the same DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Because of the code snippets I can see that your are right, but I still don't understand why, and what is the correct way to declare namespace prefixes in the markup. It seems that `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` is valid and `xmlns:test="http://example.com/test"` is not. And from further experimentation it seems that the choice of prefixes is limited (`xlink`is ok, `test` is not), but the choice of the namespaceURI is arbitrary.

Comment: @LenaSchimmel, HTML(5) in the HTML syntax only supports a restricted set of namespace declarations and attributes for SVG and/or MathML use: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#adjust-foreign-attributes. Don't expect an HTML(5) parser to recognize arbitrary namespace declarations and elements and attributes from arbitrary namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinHonnen. Now this begins to make sense to me. So am I right to assume, that there are three kinds of parsers: Those without any namespace support (pre-XHTML), those with full namespace support (XHTML) and those with very limited namespace support (HTML5)? And if I want proper namespace support, I have to switch to XHTML?

Comment: @LenaSchimmel, depending on the platform and/or programming language or API there might be options to turn namespace awareness on or off (.e.g. in the Java world you have https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware-boolean-). Inside the browser you basically have an HTML 4 or 5 or these days (simply called) HTML parser for the MIME type text/html and an XML parser for XML MIME types like `application/xml`, `application/xhtml+xml`, `image/svg+xml` and for full namespace support you need to use the XML parser.